# Add data to multidimensional arrays php in a while loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a problem adding data to a multidimensional array in a while loop.

My code lookes like this

```
while ($dataOmråde=mysql_fetch_array($område)) 
        {
            if(!in_array($dataOmråde['STED'], $aSted))
            {
                $aSted[] = $dataOmråde['STED'];
                $aOmråde[$dataOmråde['BY']]['pladsnr'] = array($dataOmråde['PLADSNR']);
            }
            else
            {
                $aOmråde[$dataOmråde['BY']]['pladsnr'] = array($dataOmråde['PLADSNR']);
            }
        }
```

But this keeps overwrithing my data so I get a result like this.

```
Array ( [Annaberg] => Array ( [pladsnr] => Array ( [0] => O_DAC_ALP_001 )
```

Bu what I want is to append data to the pladsnr array, so the result should look like this.

`Array ( [Annaberg] => Array ( [pladsnr] => Array ( [0] => O_DAC_ALP_001, [1] => new pladsnr, [2] => new pladsnr second )`

I have tried array_push but cant get i to work. Hopes someone can help:-)

Regards, Andreas

Comment: Can you `var_dump`, instead of `print_r`?... It might look easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did with `$aSted`, do:

```
$aOmråde[$dataOmråde['BY']]['pladsnr'][] = $dataOmråde['PLADSNR'];
```

Comment: Damn - so easy:-) Thanks!